# Monitoring disk with dockerized collectd

Tags: docker, monitoring, collectd

I'm trying to monitor my host's disk usage using collectd from within docker. I'm using the df collectd plugin, but I keep getting the message:

```
collectd[8]: df plugin: cu_mount_getlist failed.
collectd[8]: read-function of plugin `df' failed. Will suspend it for 20.000 seconds.
```

I'm configuring df like this in collectd.conf:

```
LoadPlugin "df"
<Plugin df>
  MountPoint "/hostfs"
</Plugin>
```

And I'm running my container with `--privileged`:

```
docker run -v "/:/hostfs:ro" --privileged collectd-statsd
```

What would cause me to get the error about `cu_mount_getlist` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the [collectd source](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/1da3305c10c8ff9a63081284cf3d4bb0f6daffd8/src/utils/mount/mount.c#L528), the function that fails tries to enumerate mounts by reading `/etc/mtab` which I'm assuming isn't mapped in your container.